# Need help understanding Cumulative Match Score (CMS) Curves

Tags: cv.computer-vision

I have been reading some papers regarding face recognition, and I often see statistics depicting the performance of the algorithms in the form of CMS or ROC curves.
I do understand what ROC curves are, but I am having difficulties understanding ranks in CMS curves. Usually the curves are plotted in charts with a % correct axis and rank axis. Can you please tell me what rank is? Or direct me to a resource that explains that?

Comment: You may want to try [stats.se], it seems to me that there are more CV people there than here. (I can migrate the question to there or [cs.se] if you want).